# how to create dict including empty csv fields as None?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
id,subid
1,a
2
3,c
4
```

When I map this to a dict, the dict is created as follows:

```
{'1':'a'}
{'3':'c'}
```

Currently it skips the ones with the empty subid. I want the empty ones to be displayed as `None`.

My current code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('filename.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r'))
for row in ricom:
   d={}
   try:
       d = {row[0]:row[15]}
       print(d)
   except IndexError:
       pass
```

I am doing the `try` and `except` because if not `row[15]` throws an `index list out of range` as some fields are empty.

My desired output should be like:

```
{'1':'a'}
{'2': None}
{'3': 'c'}
{'4': None}
```

Note: there are more than 20 columns in the csv but i've put only two as an example.

P.S: the csv file is in excel format. I mean `filename.csv`. I guess it shouldn't matter, anyway! Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read the data. You can then use `dict.get` in this fashion:

```
with open('filename.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    d = {row['id']: row.get('subid') for row in reader}

print(d)
#  {'1': 'a', '2': None, '3': 'c', '4': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `csv.DictReader`

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        print({row["id"]: row.get("subid")})
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': 'a'}
{'2': ''}
{'3': 'c'}
{'4': ''}
```